# ant filtering - fail if property not set

Tags: java, ant

I've got a ant `build.xml` that uses the `<copy>` task to copy a variety of xml files.  It uses filtering to merge in properties from a `build.properties` file.  Each environment (dev, stage, prod) has a different `build.properties` that stores configuration for that environment.

Sometimes we add new properties to the Spring XML or other config files that requires updating the `build.properties` file.

I want ant to fail fast if there are properties missing from `build.properties`.  That is, if any raw `@...@` tokens make it into the generated files, I want the build to die so that the user knows they need to add one or more properties to their local build.properties.

Is this possible with the built in tasks?  I couldn't find anything in the docs.  I'm about to write a custom ant task, but maybe I can spare myself the effort.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it in ant 1.7, using a combination of the `LoadFile` task and the `match` condition.

```
<loadfile property="all-build-properties" srcFile="build.properties"/>
<condition property="missing-properties">
    <matches pattern="@[^@]*@" string="${all-build-properties}"/>
</condition>
<fail message="Some properties not set!" if="missing-properties"/>
```

Comment: Nice.  I actually wanted to do the opposite (make sure certain key files had @'s in them -- sometimes someone accidentally checks in a version without the substitution tokens) and was able to use this approach.

Comment: Very nice.  Sorry I hadn't accepted this earlier.  Looks like what I was after.

Comment: You can nest the condition inside the fail: <fail message="Some properties not set!">
            <condition>
                <matches pattern="@[^@]*@" string="${all-build-properties}"/>
            </condition>
         </fail>

Answer (score 99):

If you are looking for a specific property, you can just use the fail task with the unless attribute, e.g.:

```xml
<fail unless="my.property">Computer says no. You forgot to set 'my.property'!</fail>
```

Refer to [the documentation for Ant's fail task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to suggest that you attempt to use `<property file="${filter.file}" prefix="filter">` to actually load the properties into Ant, and then `fail` if any of them are not set, but I think I was interpreting your problem wrong (that you wanted to fail if a specified property was not set in the properties file).

I think your best bet might be to use `<exec>` to (depending on your dev platform) do a grep for the "@" character, and then set a property to the number of occurences found. Not sure of exact syntax but...

```
<exec command="grep \"@\" ${build.dir} | wc -l" outputproperty="token.count"/>
<condition property="token.found">
    <not>
        <equals arg1="${token.count}" arg2="0"/>
    </not>
</condition>
<fail if="token.found" message="Found token @ in files"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if exec command is deprecated in your version of ant you can use redirectors, something like:

```
<exec executable="grep">
  <arg line="@ ${build.dir}"/>
  <redirector outputproperty="grep.out"/>
</exec>
<exec executable="wc" inputstring="${grep.out}">
  <arg line="-l"/>
  <redirector outputproperty="token.found"/>
</exec>
```

to create the token.found property

```
<condition property="token.found">
    <not>
        <equals arg1="${token.count}" arg2="0"/>
    </not>
</condition>
<fail if="token.found" message="Found token @ in files"/>
```

for the conditonal

Answer (score 0):

Since Ant 1.6.2 `condition` can also be nested inside `fail`.

The following macro makes it easy to conditionally check multiple properties.

```
<macrodef name="required-property">
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="prop" default="@{name}"/>
    <attribute name="if" default="___"/>
    <attribute name="unless" default="___"/>
    <sequential>
        <fail message="You must set property '@{name}'">
            <condition>
                <and>
                    <not><isset property="@{prop}"/></not>
                    <or>
                        <equals arg1="@{if}" arg2="___"/>
                        <isset property="@{if}"/>
                    </or>
                    <or>
                        <equals arg1="@{unless}" arg2="___"/>
                        <not><isset property="@{unless}"/></not>
                    </or>
                </and>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="required-property.test">
    <property name="prop" value=""/>
    <property name="cond" value="set"/>
    <required-property name="prop"/>
    <required-property name="prop" if="cond"/>
    <required-property name="prop" unless="cond"/>
    <required-property name="prop" if="cond2"/>
    <required-property name="prop" unless="cond2"/>
    <required-property name="prop" if="cond" unless="cond"/>
    <required-property name="prop" if="cond" unless="cond2"/>
    <required-property name="prop" if="cond2" unless="cond"/>
    <required-property name="prop" if="cond2" unless="cond2"/>
    <required-property name="prop2" unless="cond"/>
    <required-property name="prop2" if="cond2"/>
    <required-property name="prop2" if="cond2" unless="cond"/>
    <required-property name="prop2" if="cond" unless="cond"/>
    <required-property name="prop2" if="cond2" unless="cond2"/>
    <required-property name="success"/>
</target>
```