# How to check if a property has value in Ant

Tags: ant

I have an Ant XML file which I use for build.

I have 3 properties. I want to break the build if these properties does not contain any value. Also I want to break the build if the value is empty.

How can I do this in Ant?

I a using Ant and not Ant-contrib.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ant filtering - fail if property not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226683/ant-filtering-fail-if-property-not-set)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use conditions using the `<fail>` task:

```
<fail message="Property &quot;foo&quot; needs to be set to a value">
    <condition>
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2=""/>
            <not>
                <isset property="foo"/>
            </not>
       </or>
   </condition>
```

This is equivalent to saying *`if (not set ${foo} or ${foo} = "")`* is pseudocode. You have to read the XML conditions from the inside out.

You could have used the `<unless>` clause on the `<fail>` task if you only cared whether or not the variable was set, and not whether it has an actual value.

```
<fail message="Property &quot;foo&quot; needs to be set"
    unless="foo"/>
```

However, this won't fail if the property is set, but has no value.

---

There's a trick that can make this simpler

```
 <!-- Won't change the value of `${foo}` if it's already defined -->
 <property name="foo" value=""/>
 <fail message="Property &quot;foo&quot; has no value">
     <condition>
             <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2=""/>
     </condition>
</fail>
```

Remember that I can't reset a property! If `${foo}` already has a value, the `<property>` task above won't do anything. This way, I can eliminate the `<isset>` condition. It might be nice since you have three properties:

```
<property name="foo" value=""/>
<property name="bar" value=""/>
<property name="fubar" value=""/>
<fail message="You broke the build, you dufus">
    <condition>
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2=""/>
            <equals arg1="${bar}" arg2=""/>
            <equals arg1="${fubar}" arg2=""/>
       </or>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

Comment: Its nice to avoid nested ifs. Also with condition property & value can be set.

Comment: Great answer! I noticed the last fail statement is missing a proper closing tag --> the slash is missing and I can't correct it since editing requires to change at least 6 characters :<

Comment: @Zainodis Thanks for noticing. Fixed.

Answer (score 13):

Building on the other answers, this is my preferred form, as a Macro:

```
<!-- Macro to require a property is not blank -->
<macrodef name="prop-require">
    <attribute name="prop"/>
    <sequential>
        <fail message="Property &quot;@{prop}&quot; must be set">
            <condition>
                <not>
                    <isset property="@{prop}"/>
                </not>
           </condition>
        </fail>

        <fail message="Property &quot;@{prop}&quot; must not be empty">
            <condition>
                <equals arg1="${@{prop}}" arg2=""/>
           </condition>
        </fail>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

To Be used as:

```
<target name="deploy.war" description="Do the war deployment ;)">
    <prop-require prop="target.vm" />
    <prop-require prop="target.vip" />
    <!-- ... -->
```

For brevity you can collapse the two fail elements into one by using an `<or>`,  but I prefer my error messages to treat me like I cannot think for myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html)... or creating a target with [unless](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html)

Answer (score 0):

With [Ant addon Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) you may use patterns like :

```
 <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
...
   <fl:unless test="has.property.foo">
    ...
   </fl:unless>
...
   <fl:when test="has.property.foo">
    ...
   </fl:when>
```

Concrete check for emptyness :

```
 <fl:when test=" empty '${foo}' ">
  <fail message="Houston we have a problem!!"/>
 </fl:when>
```

A complete example, also using some equals check with 'eq' (opposite would be 'neq'):

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
  <!-- some if/then/else construct -->
  <fl:choose>
    <!-- if -->
    <when test=" '${buildtype}' eq 'prod' ">
      <!-- then -->
      <echo>..starting ProductionBuild</echo>
    </when>
    <when test=" '${buildtype}' eq 'test' ">
      <!-- then -->
      <echo>..starting TestBuild</echo>
    </when>
    <!-- else -->
    <otherwise>
      <fl:unless test="has.property.dummybuild">
        <fail message="No valid buildtype !, found => '${buildtype}'"/>
      </fl:unless>
      <echo>.. is DummyBuild</echo>
    </otherwise>
  </fl:choose>
</project>
```

output with ant -f build.xml -Dbuildtype=prod
 or
ant -f build.xml -Dbuildtype=prod -Ddummybuild=whatever

```
[echo] ..starting ProductionBuild
```

output with typo => ant - build.xml -Dbuildtype=testt

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/rosebud/workspace/AntTest/build.xml:21: No valid buildtype !, found => 'testt'
```

output with ant -f build.xml -Ddummybuild=whatever

```
[echo] .. is DummyBuild
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on an older version of Ant, so isset wasn't available. Instead I used the following notation with the double $ in the equals.

```
  <target name="xxx">
        <echo message="${contextRoot}" />
        <if>
            <!-- check if the contextRoot property is defined. -->
            <equals arg1="${contextRoot}" arg2="$${contextRoot}" />
            <then>
                <!-- it isn't set, set a default -->
                <property name="contextRoot" value="/WebAppCtx" />
            </then>
        </if>
        <echo message="${contextRoot}" />
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<condition property="isPropertySet" value="true" else="false">
    <and>
        <isset property="my_property"/>
        <length string="${my_property}" trim="true" when="greater" length="0"/>
    </and>
</condition>
<fail unless="isPropertySet" message="The property my_property is not set."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Ant 1.9.1, it is possible to add `if` and `unless` attributes on all
tasks and nested elements using special namespaces.

In order to use this feature you need to add the following namespace declarations

```
xmlns:if="ant:if"
xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
```

The `if` and `unless` namespaces support the following conditions:

- `true` - true if the value of the attribute evaluates to true
- `blank` - true if the value of the attribute is null or empty
- `set` - true if the specified property is set

Sample:

```
<project name="tryit"
 xmlns:if="ant:if"
 xmlns:unless="ant:unless">
 <exec executable="java">
   <arg line="-X" if:true="${showextendedparams}"/>
   <arg line="-version" unless:true="${showextendedparams}"/>
 </exec>
 <condition property="onmac">
   <os family="mac"/>
 </condition>
 <echo if:set="onmac">running on MacOS</echo>
 <echo unless:set="onmac">not running on MacOS</echo>
</project>
```

[From Ant manual "If And Unless"](https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html)