# ant - if doesn't support the "name" attribute

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

i have a requirement that as follows.
I have a .properties file (with name=value pair) from which i am reading couple of properties.
i want to check a particular property exist or not.
i am getting the error with `if doesn't support the "name" attribute` for the following code.
where JavaProjectName,projDir are the names getting from the .properties file.

```
<if name="${JavaProjectName}" exists="true">
<property name="importJavaProject" value="${projDir}/${JavaProjectName}"/>
</if>
```

can you please tell me where am i doing wrong.

Comment: possibkle duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207680/how-to-check-if-a-property-has-value-in-ant

Comment: i am not checking the empty values,i want to check the property existence in .properties file

Comment: check for isset tag in the post ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the document](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) of `<if>` task first. It doesn't support the way you wrote.

It should be:

```
<if>
    <isset property="JavaProjectName" />
    <then>
        <property name="importJavaProject" value="${projDir}/${JavaProjectName}"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

However, you want to set a property `importJavaProject` when another property `JavaProjectName` has been set before (in the build file or in a properties file imported). So, what if `JavaProjectName` has not been set?

You should either think of an `<else>` part, or fail the build.

If you just want to check for existence and fail the build when it does not exist, just use [`<fail>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html):

```
<fail unless="JavaProjectName"/>
```

Also check [`Condition`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) task and ["Supported conditions"](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html).

---

Addition:

Also read the question posted by ManMohan in the comment more carefully. For "check the property existence in .properties file", the accepted answer of that question checks both "whether the property has been set" and "whether its value is empty".

Comment: Thanks coolcfan for your answer.But it did not work for me.I know to read the documents ok.I have seen this piece of code some where in additional ant tasks.My requirement is as follows

Comment: My requirement is as follows If the name and value pair for JavaProjectName is there then it has to assign the value for importJavaProject ,else it should not throw error.It has to assign the remaining values to the names.If the importJavaProject value is not assigned then it should not import the projects.This is my requirement.If you can please help me out.

Comment: @Thiru what do u mean by "it has to assign the remaining values to the names"? Also, if you don't need `else` handling, if you just want to skip setting the property `importJavaProject` when `JavaProjectName` hasn't been set, then the correct usage of `<if>` above is enough.

Comment: Changed my code to support above scenario.my problem is resolved now.Thank you very much for your support.