# Checking the "value" of "value" attribute of ant Property tag/element

Tags: xml, ant, build, build-automation, xmltask

I wanted to check if a property value has a value which is supposed to be read from another file in ant

can any body please without an additional jar.

```
<property name="a" value="${input.password}" />
```

wanted to check if input.password has got the value or not from xyz.properties file or not

many thanks
Jib

P.S: Actually I have to check this line password=mypassword is exist in .properties file or not  with ant script. Another way is welcome !

Edit: I am doing from one of the referenced solutions but not succeeding:

```
<property file="..\..\xyz\application.properties" prefix="input" /> 

<property name="foo" value="${input.password}"/>
 <fail message="Property &quot;foo&quot; has no value">
     <condition>
          <not>
             <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2=""/>
          </not>
     </condition>
</fail>
```

Always getting this message:"Property "foo" has no value" regardless of this line exists or not:password=de in application properties.

Comment: Also you can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9220635/706695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using the  `<fail message="db.schema is not defined!" unless="db.schema"/>` block this for example will fail if db.schema is not defined. You might find some of [this](http://www.javaranch.com/ant/properties.jsp) and useful, is this what  you're looking for?

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226683/ant-filtering-fail-if-property-not-set) too. Oh OK I see what you mean now, please try this (I'm using Ant 1.8.2):
this is build.xml :

```
<project name="Bla" default="build" basedir=".">
<target name="build">
    <property file="bla.properties"/>

<fail>
     <condition>
       <not>
        <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2="bodo"/>
       </not>
     </condition>
</fail>
</target>
</project>
```

The file bla.properties contains `foo=boo`, and it currently fails, if I change `bodo` to `boo`, is succeeds.

Comment: so far I didn't get the answer of my question. I have tried all the solutions referenced; but none of them is working.

Comment: yes definitely the property has value; but the value got the value or not that needs to be checked :<property name="a" value="${input.password}" />. This above check a exist or not or it has value so yes but that is not what i want (correct me if I am wrong):

Answer (score 1):

```
<project name="demo" default="dosomething">

    <loadproperties srcFile="check.properties"/>

    <target name="check">
        <input message="Enter value" addproperty="input"/>

        <condition property="input.matches">
            <equals arg1="${input}" arg2="${valuefromfile}"/>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="dosomething" depends="check" if="input.matches">
        <echo message="hello world"/>
    </target>

</project>
```